# What is the advantage to set cell subviews frame in layoutSubviews method vs in cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Tags: ios, uitableview, layoutsubviews

I am just thinking what is the advantage to set up frames, coordinates / sizes in `layoutSubviews` in case `UITableViewCell` is subclassed vs directly when cell is created in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

As I see if `autoresizingmask` properly do his job to set views frame size meanwhile rotation, then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should be enough to use?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

It's the cell's job to determine how to lay out its subviews (hence the method `layoutSubviews`), not the tableView's data source. If the cell needs information, it's the data source's responsibility to give the cell that information, but after that the cell should be laying itself out.

Comment: I prefer this: *use `layoutSubviews` to perform additional manual changes above and beyond any autoresizing behaviours*